Problems with Venturis font installation with Miktex on Windows
I am using Miktex on Windows 11 and up to mid 2024 I employed the venturis font in one of my documents simply via
\usepackage{venturis}
and everything worked fine.
Since then (presumably due to an update) I get the error
! LaTeX Error: File `venturis.sty' not found.
A minimal example would be
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{venturis}

\begin{document}
    hello world
\end{document}

As the same example obviously runs with Texlive on linux or in overleaf I suspect an issue with my miktex installation.
I tried the following:

uninstalling/reinstalling the package
uninstalling/reinstalling Miktex

At this point I run out of ideas and very happy for your help :)

You can use texlive on windows, too

there was a packaging bug in miktex which would have caused this error.

looks like a packaging bug. You can report such issues here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/456 (& welcome, by the way:).)

thank you for the quick, almost instant replies, and for appending venturisadf to the correct issue :)
